# Xcode custom key binding to navigate to Main.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I know that Xcode has the "Open Quickly" key binding (⇧ + ⌘ + O). Is there some way to set a custom key binding so that I can navigate directly to a specific file in the Project navigator? I'm particularly wanting to have an easy way to go to Main.storyboard.

Comment: You'll have to make a plugin :)

Comment: Okay, thanks, I thought that might be the case. Though I'm not sure that saving two key strokes is worth the work to make a plugin.

Comment: The keystrokes part is just a minor thing. Many plugins have a keyboard shortcut associated with them. The cool part of the plugin would be the ability to open to Main.storyboard. You could even add shortcuts for opening it in a new tab and new window, as well as allowing the user to change the name of the storyboard file associated with the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Maybe I'll take this on after my current project.